# Console Error : Moment Timezone requires Moment.js. in Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, momentjs, moment-timezone

I have developed an application in vue + laravel, and used moment library. it was working fine on local and live environment, but suddenly yesterday in live environment it stopped working.

browser console.

```
Moment Timezone requires Moment.js. See https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/use-it/browser/
TypeError: t.version is undefined
```

i tried running `npm install moment-timezone` and `npm update` but not working.

Comment: Install the `moment` library also.

Comment: i have already tried it

package.json file

"moment": "^2.24.0",
 "moment-timezone": "^0.5.28",

Comment: Could you give us reproducible example? When you installed `moment-timezone` and `moment` package it should be already working unless you edited package json manually and didn't do `npm install`

Comment: i actually don't know if someone has changed. because server is owned by client, we are just pushing code using gitlab and pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my error by changing package json file manually.

i just removed updgrade symbol.

```
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.28",
```

to

```
    "moment": "2.18.1",
    "moment-timezone": "0.5.28",
```